# Two network/wi-fi icons in the system tray

Tags: networking, wireless, kubuntu, icons, system-tray

I have been having issues with my internet connection.

I have noticed that after installing some 'software updates' on my installation of Kubuntu that I now have two network icons appearing in my system tray, at the lower right hand of the desktop.
One of the icons is a blue colored wifi type icon and the other is the same though gray.
[system tray showing two network icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9S2M.png)

Since noticing these two icons after the update. I have been expecting drop-outs in my internet connection.
Can anyone advise me, as to how to resolve this issue? Thank you. I am running Kubuntu 22.

```
$uname -a
Linux chris-Aspire-8730 5.15.0-48-generic #54-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 26 13:26:29 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:printing-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:security- 
11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Comment: Expecting drop outs or experiencing drop outs? BTW Always give a full version number.

Comment: "experiencing" that was supposed to be yeah.

Do you mind if I ask which command you would recommend to give the full version number?